# Python code netcat tool

Tags: python, eof, netcat

I have been working on a netcat listener written in Python, and I am having some trouble with the script continuing to read from STDIN until it receives a EOF marker. The following is example commands that I have been running:

This does successfully set up a listener on the localhost as I can see from running a `netstat -antp` command

```
./netcat.py -l -p 9999 -c
```

I then open another terminal window and run this command to act as a client connecting to localhost on port 9999

```
./netcat.py -t localhost -p 9999
```

What I should be seeing is a simple shell getting sent back after I hit <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> and send the EOF. Instead nothing happens and the shell is not sent back.

Code below, any insight would be much appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import socket
import getopt
import threading
import subprocess

#define some global variables
listen              = False
command             = False
upload              = False
execute             = ""
target              = ""
upload_destination  = ""
port                = 0

def usage():
    print "BHP Net Tool"
    print
    print "Usage: bhpnet.py -t target_host -p port"
    print "-l --listen      -listen on [host]:[port] for incoming connections"
    print "-e --execute=file_to_run         -execute the given file upon receiving a connection"
    print "-c --command                 -initialize a command shell"
    print "-u --upload=destination           -Upon receiving connection upload a file and write to [destination]"
    print
    print
    print "Examples: "
    print "bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -c"
    print "bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -u=c:\\target.exe"
    print "bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -e=\"cat /etc/passwd\""
    print "echo 'ABCDEFGHI' | ./bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 135"
    sys.exit(0)

def main():
    global listen
    global port
    global execute
    global command
    global upload_destination
    global target

    if not len(sys.argv[1:]):
    usage()

    #read the commandline options
    try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"hle:t:p:cu:",["help","listen","execute","target","port","command","upload"])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print str(err)
    usage()

    for o,a in opts:
    if o in ("-h", "--help"):
        usage()
    elif o in ("-l", "--listen"):
        listen = True 
    elif o in ("-e", "--execute"):
        execute = a
    elif o in ("-c", "--commandshell"):
        command = True
    elif o in ("-u", "--upload"):
        upload_destination = a
    elif o in ("-t", "--target"):
        target = a
    elif o in ("-p", "--port"):
        port = int(a)
    else:
        assert False,"Unhandled Option"

    #are we going to listen or just send data from stdin?
    if not listen and len(target) and port > 0:

    #read in the buffer from the commandline
    #this will block, so send CTRL-D if not sending input
    #to stdin
    buffer = sys.stdin.read()

    #send data off
    client_sender(buffer)

    #we are going to listen and potentially
    #upload things, execute commands, and drop a shell back
    #depending on our command line options above
    if listen:

    server_loop()

def client_sender(buffer):

    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
    #connect to our target host
    client.connect((target,port))

    if len(buffer):
        client.send(buffer)

    while True:

        #now wait for data back
        recv_len = 1
        response = ""

        while recv_len:

            data     = client.recv(4096)
            recv_len = len(data)
            response+= data

            if recv_len < 4096:
                break

    print response,

    #wait for more input
    buffer = raw_input("")
    buffer += "\n"

    #send it off
    client.send(buffer)

    except:
    print "[*] Exception! Exiting"

    #tear down the connection
    client.close()

def server_loop():
    global target

    #if no target is defined, we listen on all interfaces
    if not len(target):
    target = "0.0.0.0"

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((target,port))
    server.listen(5)

    while True:
    client_socket, addr = server.accept()

    #spin off a thread to handle our new client
    client_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_handler, args=(client_socket,))
    client_thread.start()

def run_command(command):

    #trim the newline
    command = command.rstrip()

    #run the command get the output back
    try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(command,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    except:
    output = "Failed to execute command.\r\n"

    #send the output back to the Client
    return output

def client_handler(client_socket):
    global upload
    global execute
    global command

    #check for upload
    if len(upload_destination):

    #read in all of the bytes and write to our destination
    file_buffer = ""

    #keep reading data until none is available
    while True:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)

        if not data:
            break
        else:
            file_buffer += data

    #now we take these bytes and try to write them out
    try:
        file_descriptor = open(upload_destination,"wb")
        file_descriptor.write(file_buffer)
        file_descriptor.close()

        #acknowledge that we wrote the file out
        client_socket.send("Successfully saved file to %s\r\n" % upload_destination)
    except:
        client_socket.send("Failed to save file to %s\r\n" % upload_destination)

    #check for command execution
    if len(execute):

    #run the command
    output = run_command(execute)

    client_socket.send(output)

    #now we go into another loop if a command shell was requested
    if command:

    while True:
        #show a simple prompt
        client_socket.send("<BHP:#> ")

        #now we receive until we see a linefeed (enter key)
        cmd_buffer = ""
        while "\n" not in cmd_buffer:
            cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(1024)

        #send back the command output
        response = run_command(cmd_buffer)

        #send back the response
        client_socket.send(response)  

main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by `netcat listener`? Netcat is just very simple socket server/client tool, nothing more than that.

Comment: If you want to terminate your program after only one connection, don't accept() connections in a loop, instead terminate the socket after the first connection is accepted.

Comment: There's a whole lot of code here that is almost certainly not relevant to the problem. Can you write a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of giving us a dump of everything?